# User Groups with specific Roles

Tags: jhipster, user-management

I´ve got a JHipster microservice application layout.
I would like to have different Groups with users. Users can be in multiple groups. Some other Micorservices must declare their entitys as ownable by groups.

The groups are getting some roles. Group admins can assign these roles to members.

My Question now: Should I place these groups and roles inside the UAA-JHipster Server or in a serparate microservice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Gitter Chat answer: UAA.
UAA is responsible for the authorization and therefore intended for my requirements.